# How does the overloading of the assignment operator in combination of the length function work?

Tags: r, operator-overloading

How does the mutating implementation of `length()` actually work?

Example: Given a vector `v`, how does this set the length to 12?

```
length(v) <- 12
```

Can I create my own function that can overload an operator in the same way?

Example: Set every other element to  7

```
everyOther(v) <- 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those assignment functions are just that, functions.  They can be written in the following form (note the backticks - they must be used), where `fname` distinguishes the function name.

```
`fname<-` <- function(x, value) { ... }
```

So your `everyOther` assignment function can be written as

```
`everyOther<-` <- function(x, value) {
    x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- value
    x
}
```

And we can use it just as we would `length(x) <- value`

```
v <- 1:20
everyOther(v) <- 7
v
# [1]  1  7  3  7  5  7  7  7  9  7 11  7 13  7 15  7 17  7 19  7
```

Comment: I was wondering if you meant `names` in your example rather than `name`?

Comment: @prosoitos - I didn't.   I used `name` to mean the name of the function.

Comment: Got you. I thought you were using an existing accessor function as an example and I didn't realize that "name" was used to mean "name of function". Great explanation by the way :)